# Merging a list of dicts into one dict with items appended to a list

Tags: python

```py
def merge_dicts(list_of_dicts: list, missval=None):
    '''Merges a list of dicts, having common keys into a single dict
    with items appended to a list

    >>> d1 = {'a' : 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
    >>> d2 = {'a':4, 'b':5 }
    >>> d3 = {'d': 5}
    >>> merge_dicts([d1, d2, d3], 'NA')
    {'a': [1, 4, 'NA'], 'b': [2, 5, 'NA'],
    'c': [3, 'NA', 'NA'], 'd': ['NA', 'NA', 5]}
    '''
    all_keys = []
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        for k in d.keys():
            if k not in all_keys:
                all_keys.append(k)

    merged = {}
    for k in all_keys:
        for d in list_of_dicts:
            try:
                merged[k].append(d.get(k, missval))
            except KeyError:
                merged[k] = [d.get(k)]

    return(merged)
```

The function docstring is self explanatory. Is there a more efficient way to do this without having to write two for loops? One to find all the keys in all the dicts, and other to make a merged dict?

Comment: @Close voters- how is this opinion-based? I think it's a pretty clear question

Comment: I am new to stack overflow. What does opinion based mean in context of my question? Maybe I should rephrase the wording of my question as "I want my code to be readable as well as efficient with minimal redundancy".

Comment: A "better way" is primarily opinion-based. Unless the language you are using has an official specification on the "best" idiomatic code for what you are trying to do, different people have different opinions on what is "better".

Comment: Adding on to @SOFe's comment, specifying "better" _in what way_ may also be enough. It looks like you may be looking for a more _efficient_ way to do this -- if so, just edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: I honestly think, stackoverflow should have a separate tag of *is there a better/efficient way" of doing this? Only top users (above a certain criteria) should be allowed to answer the questions. The questions may be put on hold and subject to review by intermediate users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `set` for creating the list of keys, if you don't care about their order. You could create it using a comprehension.

For the second part, you can use a dict comprehension, and create each list with a list comprehension:

```
def merge_dicts(list_of_dicts: list, missval=None):
    '''Merges a list of dicts, having common keys into a single dict
    with items appended to a list

    >>> d1 = {'a' : 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
    >>> d2 = {'a':4, 'b':5 }
    >>> d3 = {'d': 5}
    >>> merge_dicts([d1, d2, d3], 'NA')
    {'a': [1, 4, 'NA'], 'b': [2, 5, 'NA'],
    'c': [3, 'NA', 'NA'], 'd': ['NA', 'NA', 5]}
    '''
    all_keys = {key for d in list_of_dicts for key in d.keys()}
    merged = {k: [d.get(k, missval) for d in list_of_dicts] for k in all_keys}

    return(merged)


d1 = {'a' : 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
d2 = {'a':4, 'b':5 }
d3 = {'d': 5}
merge_dicts([d1, d2, d3], 'NA')


#{'a': [1, 4, 'NA'],
# 'b': [2, 5, 'NA'],
# 'c': [3, 'NA', 'NA'],
# 'd': ['NA', 'NA', 5]}
```

Comment: nice, and you can drop the `.keys()` i think

Comment: Yes, as iterating on the dict iterates on its keys. I hesitated on this one, and finally left `.keys()` to make it more explicit...

Comment: This is an elegant solution, but it still seems inefficient to me: why is `all_keys` needed at all? Although this way of creating `all_keys` should be more efficient, so it's still a good solution and it's nice to have a `missval` for cases not in the original dicts.

Comment: Very clean comprehensions indeed. And yes, I also always iterate on ```.keys()``` as *explicit is better than implicit*

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution with `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_dicts(list_of_dicts: list, missval=None):
    result = defaultdict(lambda: [missval] * len(list_of_dicts))
    for i, d in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
        for k, v in d.items():
            result[k][i] = v
    return dict(result)

d1 = {'a' : 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
d2 = {'a':4, 'b':5 }
d3 = {'d': 5}
print(merge_dicts([d1, d2, d3], 'NA'))
# {'a': [1, 4, 'NA'], 'b': [2, 5, 'NA'], 'c': [3, 'NA', 'NA'], 'd': ['NA', 'NA', 5]}
```

Comment: I like this solution, as it does away with the unified list of keys, which is completely unnecessary to accomplish the desired task.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas, you could use the dictionary to fill a dataframe, and transform it back to a dictionary again:

```
pd.DataFrame([d1, d2, d3]).to_dict()
  {'a': {0: 1.0, 1: 4.0, 2: nan},
   'b': {0: 2.0, 1: 5.0, 2: nan},
   'c': {0: 3.0, 1: nan, 2: nan},
   'd': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 5.0}}
```